# Make content of an HTML <summary> element searchable

Tags: html

On a FAQ page, I use an HTML `<summary>` element to hide the answers of the questions until the user clicks on a question to open the answer.

```html
<details>
  <summary>Question</summary>
  Answer
</details>
```

A text search on that page finds text in the answer only when it is expanded. Is there a way to make the answer texts searchable even when they are not expanded? If the text search finds text in a non-expanded answer, the answer should automatically expand.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is totally up to the implementation of the webbrowser whether or not it searches in hidden contents, but I probably will never do that, because that would give a really weird user experience to the end user: the browser would tell the user that it found text, but the user cannot see it.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve exactly, but you would probably be best of to implement some kind of Javascript or some serverside (like PHP) solution to your problem.

Comment: I clarified in the question what should happen if “hidden” text is found: “If the text search finds text in a non-expanded answer, the answer should automatically expand.”

Comment: Yes and like I explain that is totally up to the browser, so you'd have to implement a solution built with Javascript, PHP, or something like that.